# Cannot connect to my backend https socket server from my https React App

Tags: https, socket.io, vite

In my backend I used socket.io & https packages:
I created a folder called certs and I passed these commands in /backend/certs:
*$ mkcert create-ca*
*$ mkcert create-cert*

// server.js: this is where we create the express and socket.io server

```js
const fs = require("fs");
const https = require("https");
const http = require("http");
const express = require("express");
const cors = require("cors");
const socketio = require("socket.io");

const app = express();
app.use(cors());
app.use(express.static(__dirname + "/public"));
app.use(express.json());

const key = fs.readFileSync("./certs/create-cert-key.pem");
const cert = fs.readFileSync("./certs/create-cert.pem");

const expressServer = https.createServer({ key, cert }, app); // for local development https
const io = socketio(expressServer, {
  cors: [
    "https://localhost:5173",
    "https://192.168.0.3:5173",
    "https://localhost:5174",
    "https://192.168.0.3:5174",
  ],
});

expressServer.listen(9000);
module.exports = { io, expressServer, app };
```

// socketServer.js:

```js
const io = require('./server').io;
io.on('connection',socket=>{
    console.log(socket.id,"has connected")
}
```

in the frontend I used vite-plugin-mkcert & socket.io-client packages:
also here I created a folder called certs and I passed these commands in /frontend/certs:
*$ mkcert create-ca
$ mkcert create-cert*

// vite.config.js:

```js
import { defineConfig } from 'vite'
import react from '@vitejs/plugin-react'
import mkcert from 'vite-plugin-mkcert'
export default defineConfig({
  server: {
    https: {
      key: './certs/create-cert-key.pem',
      cert: './certs/create-cert.pem'
    }
  },
  plugins: [mkcert({ hosts: ['https://192.168.0.3:5173', 'https://localhost:5173'] }), react()],
})
```

// then in App.js:

```js
import { io } from 'socket.io-client';

function App() {
  useEffect(() => {
    io.connect('https://localhost:9000')
  }, [])
  return <>Something</>
}
```

So when I launch my React app, I got this message from Vite in the terminal:
➜  Local:   https://localhost:5173/
➜  Network: https://192.168.0.3:5173/
➜  Network: https://172._______:5173/

and I got this error printed in MY CONSOLE:
socket__io-client.js?v=16b5eae2:898:
GET https://localhost:9000/socket.io/?EIO=4&transport=polling&t=OrAK9MP net::ERR_CERT_COMMON_NAME_INVALID

In the terminal (backend serverv) I did NOT get any message printed like: *some_id* has connected

I test the socket server with postman, in the terminal and I got the expected message printed:
MgVyLbeo4f8-NoUBAAAB has connected

Comment: do you get the same error if you start react app with a different browser? chrome extensions might interfere

Comment: I test it with Mozilla and I get a different error message:
Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at https://localhost:9000/socket.io/?EIO=4&transport=polling&t=OrBJZVb. (Reason: CORS request did not succeed). Status code:

Answer (score 0):

can you set up `socket.io` cors like this:

```
const io = require("socket.io")(expressServer, {
    cors: {
      origin: "*",
      methods: ["GET", "POST"],
    },
  });
```